# ES6 import - What does the question mark mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I noticed while digging through material UI's codebase that some of the files have import statements that include a `?` mark in the import path. For example `import * as pageProps from 'docs/data/material/getting-started/overview/overview.md?@mui/markdown';` notice the `?@mui/markdown` at the end. What does this mean? Or do?

Comment: Looks like a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). Could you provide more context (e.g a direct link where this is in use)

Comment: Here is a [link](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/docs/pages/material-ui/getting-started/overview.js) to the file I referenced in my example.

[@mui/markdown](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/packages/markdown) is a package in the mui repo that parses markdown.

It looks like it is maybe importing the markdown file and using the @mui/markdown package to parse it?

Comment: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/b6d46ee4447e2fa321f3e61017da95211c656ac7/docs/scripts/reportBrokenLinks.js#L88

Comment: So all it's doing is using that as a way to identify a content file, so it can test for broken links?